# Using C++ library with Matlab

Tags: matlab, gcc

Hi I read one similar question-  on using mex + nvcc linker problems with standard library. My problem  is similar as I have code which compiles Ok with gcc on the Mac OS X. ( I am a beginner)

## Code

```
gcc -lstdc++ trnr.c -o trnr   works fine
```

## Error

But I get these errors when I use mex

> Building with 'Xcode with Clang'.
>   Error using mex
>
> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "_mexFunction", referenced from:
>        -exported_symbol[s_list] command line option
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Not sure how to procede can anyone help

Comment: The way mex works is that from your compiled code, Matlab will call a function `void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) `. If you don't have that *exact* function, the linking step will fail. From the error, it looks like you don't have a function with that exact name and arguments?

Comment: If you haven't done it already, you may want to checkout [this tutorial](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/standalone-example.html).

Comment: While `mex` is typically the preferred way when you have the source code available, note that `loadlibrary` is an alternative.

Comment: OOPS!!  I did know about the calls but I was surprised by the error message - thanks for taking the trouble to look at this.